# How to implement a language / culture (that is not yet supported) in ActiveReports 11?

Tags: internationalization, reporting, multilingual, activereports

We already have a vast group of `.rpx` files that contain report definitions in german. We have used scripting to translate some of the text to romansh (official swiss language used by <1% of population), yet it has been requested.
The vision now is to create reports in french and maybe italian as well. Yet we are well aware that the current scripting approach like:

```
if (txtSprache.Text == "RM")
{
    lblAbonnentenNr.Text = "Abo-nr.:";
    lblAbrechnungVon.Text = "Quen dils:";
    lblBis.Text = "  -";
    lblZahlbarBis.Text = "Pagabel tochen:";
    lblObjekt.Text = "Object:";
    lblRechnungsNr.Text = "Nr. dil quen:";
    lblRechnungsdatum.Text = "Datum da quen:";
    lblERechnungsID.Text = "ID";
    lblAbonnent.Text = "Abonnent";
}
```

Is not well suited for that. I have been asked to create options for I18n support. Quoted from the [AR11 documentation](https://www.grapecity.com/en/docs/platforms/activereports-11):

> **To localize a Report at design time**
>   1.  Click the gray area around the design surface to select the Report in the Properties window.
>   2.  In the Properties window, drop down the Culture or Language property and select the culture that you want to apply to the report.

The old default was: (default, inherit), I know changed that to German (Switzerland). I couldn't find any difference, no new stuff under `C:\Program Files (x86)\GrapeCity\ActiveReports 11\Localization`, nor elsewhere in the xml. 
How do I add a new language sheet / values for the current report and it's labels?
How do I add a culture that does not exist yet? (In worst case I'd use any local and use it as romansh, since only german, italian, french and unlikely english could be used)

Answer (score 1):

The Language property, mentioned in the documentation, works for the code-based templates only. When you set the new language by this property VSID creates the additional resource file, e.g. myreport.jp-JP.resx.
In such case, the compiled report will upload the needed resources according to CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture value. It does not work for RPX(xml-based) templates.
So if you want to use this functionality, you need to convert xml-based to code-based templates.

The Culture property helps only to specify a locale for OutputFormat feature(e.g. conversion to currency).

For RPX templates localization, I think you could combine the external localization resource files with the current scripting approach, I mean the loading of the resource file in script and update the report items.

Thanks,

Comment: Has AR a built in conversion tool for rpx to resx? I can imagine not being the first one with that issue, are there best practices?

Comment: 1) Add the new code-based report template to the project in Visual Studio; 2) Use Report->Load Layout menu to load the content from RPX report.